# Having trouble with FIELDPROC on a database (Column Encryption on Iseries)

Tags: encryption, passwords, ibm-midrange, password-encryption, db2-400

I used **Listing 3** in the following link to create a FIELDPROC program QGPL/MOBHOMEPAS which should encrypt a variable char column [Field Encryption in DB2 for i](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1101encryptenhance/#icomments)

I compiled the RPGLE program and I created a separate database DBMLIB/UMAAAP00 as follows

```
A          R UMAAAF00                  TEXT('-          
A                                      TEST ENCRYPTION')
A*                                                      
A            IPIAAA        20A         VARLEN(20)       
A            KYGAAA        11S 2       COLHDG('SALARY')
```

I then use strsql to alter the table and protect IPIAAA

```
ALTER TABLE DBMLIB/UMAAAP00 alter column IPIAAA set FIELDPROC
QGPL.MOBHOMEPAS  

ALTER COMPLETED FOR TABLE UMAAAP00 IN DBMLIB.
```

For some reason when I go in to add entries through upddta directly to the file itself and then do a wrkqry to query and file and view them I don't see them as encrypted.

Is this not how it's supposed to work? Is anyone able to assist me with the logic? Ultimately, I'd like to create a simple table from scratch that has a single 20 character or so password column as encrypted.

Comment: Did you use the example code exactly as provided? Or did you add any code to restrict decoding for certain users?  Is QGPL.MOBHOMEPAS available to the job that runs RUNQRY?

Answer (score 1):

If the code being utilized for the named FieldProc program QGPL.MOBHOMEPAS was modeled-after [an effective copy of] the source code that was found at the URL from the OP [which BTW includes a position-to request to the comments section... Why?], then that code is implemented using the base-level of the DB2 for IBM i 7.1 SQL FieldProc support, not the **next** [enhanced] level of support in which the **masking** feature was added.  That is, every invocation other than for function-code=8 will necessarily always be an Encode or a Decode operation for which any *masking* of the data is unsupported, because changing the data [with that level of support] would corrupt the data in the TABLE.

Note [from http://www.mcpressonline.com/rpg/db2-field-procedures-finally-support-conditional-masking.html] the differences in the coding requirements described for the pre-masking-support [eight parameters] and since-masking-support [nine parameters] as the pre-requisite to have the Run Query (RUNQRY) and Update Data (UPDDTA) features *mask the data* that is presented to the user:

> The new FieldProc Masking support revolves around two main components.
>   The first component is a new parameter that was added to the parameter
>   lists that the DB2 engine passes to the FieldProc program on each
>   decode call. This new parameter controls whether or not the FieldProc
>   program can return a masked value. There are some DB2 operations—such
>   as the RGZPFM (Reorganize Physical File Member) command and trigger
>   processing—that always require the clear-text version of the data to
>   be returned. The second component is a new special SQLState value
>   ('09501') that is to be returned by the FieldProc program whenever it
>   is passed a masked value on the encode call. This prevents the masked
>   value from being encoded, which would result in the original data
>   value being lost. When this special SQLState value is returned, DB2
>   will ignore the encoded value that is passed back by the FieldProc
>   program and instead use the value that's currently stored in the
>   record image for that column.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason when I go in to add entries through upddta directly to
>   the file itself and then do a wrkqry to query and file and view them I
>   don't see them as encrypted.  Is this not how it's supposed to work?

No, that's not how it's supposed to work.  The data will be encoded on disk only. 
  When you view the data it will be decoded automatically by the FIELDPROC program no matter what you're using to view it (WRKQRY [yuck], DFU, STRSQL, whatever).  This is how it works regardless of field *masking* (which is different/additional functionality).